# ¿Como se comparan 2 diccionarios para saber si tienen el mismo item o key?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Necesito comparar 2 diccionarios y devolver un diccionario con todos los elmento de ambos. Ejemplo:

```
dic1 = {'a': 2, 'e': 5, 'u': 1}
dic2 = {'a': 3, 'e': 2, 'i': 2}
```

entonces devolver uno de los dos completo con todos los elementos:

```
dic1 = {'a': 5, 'e': 7, 'i': 2, 'u': 1}
```

Answer (score 2):

Creo que la forma más sencilla, sería:

```
dic1 = {'a': 2, 'e': 5, 'u': 1}
dic2 = {'a': 3, 'e': 2, 'i': 2}

newdict = { k: dic1.get(k, 0) + dic2.get(k, 0) for k in set(dic1) | set(dic2) }
print(newdict)

{'a': 5, 'i': 2, 'u': 1, 'e': 7}
```

Es decir:

- Combinamos todas las claves mediante `set(dic1) | set(dic2)`
- Las recorremos y sumamos entre ambos diccionarios. Al usar `get()` con un valor default no hay problema en caso que una clave no exista en uno de los dos diccionarios

Answer (score 2):

Si quieres obtener todas las claves únicas presentes en al menos uno de los diccionarios puedes usar la unión de conjuntos:

```
>>> set(dic1) | set(dic2)
{'a', 'e', 'u', 'i'}
```

Lo que realmente buscas es unir ambos diccionarios y sumar los valores, puedes aplicar la unión de conjuntos junto a `dict.get` en un diccionario por compresión:

```
dic1 = {'a': 2, 'e': 5, 'u': 1}
dic2 = {'a': 3, 'e': 2, 'i': 2}


res = {key: dic1.get(key, 0) + dic2.get(key, 0) for key in set(dic1) | set(dic2)}
```

---

> ```
> >>> res
> {'u': 1, 'a': 5, 'e': 7, 'i': 2}
> ```

La construcción del diccionario por compresión es eficiente, el problema es que se requiere iterar dos veces por cada diccionario, además de la construcción de un conjunto por cada uno y uno final resultado de la unión. Esto hace que para diccionarios extensos sea más eficiente en términos de memoria y en tiempo de ejecución a partir de cierto punto iterar sobre cada diccionario secuencialmente:

```
from collections import defaultdict

res = defaultdict(int)
for dict_ in (dic1, dic2):
    for key, value in dict_.items():
        res[key] += value
```

---

> ```
> >>> res
> defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'a': 5, 'e': 7, 'u': 1, 'i': 2})
> >>> dict(res)
> {'a': 5, 'e': 7, 'u': 1, 'i': 2}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Las soluciones de los compañeros están realmente bien. Se me ocurre otra que es menos elegante y concisa porque no recurre a la compresión, pero que mejora la eficiencia en cuanto a tiempos de ejecución se refiere:

```py
dic1 = {'a': 2, 'e': 5, 'u': 1}
dic2 = {'a': 3, 'e': 2, 'i': 2}

dic3 = dic1.copy()

for k, v in dic2.items():
    dic3[k] = v if k not in dic3.keys() else v + dic3[k]
```

Lo que da como resultado:

```
>>> dic3
{'a': 5, 'u': 1, 'e': 7, 'i': 2}
```